# How to add an IP address to an existing network adapter in Windows?

Tags: c, winapi, networking

I am trying to add a new IP address to a local network adapter in Windows using the Windows API. Are there functions to do this in the Windows API, and if so, what are they?

I am not trying to create virtual network adapters, but simply trying to assign multiple IP addresses to the same adapter.

Comment: +1 for such a well composed question. Most newcomers are usually really sloppy.

Comment: Thanks. I rarely ask questions, but when I do, I try to make them clear and concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [AddIPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365801(VS.85).aspx) and [DeleteIPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365875(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

See [AddIpAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365801%28VS.85%29.aspx) in the IP Helper library

Answer (score 0):

include iphlpapi.h
and function to use:

"""

```
ULONG NTEContext = 0;
ULONG NTEInstance = 0;
DWORD status;

status = AddIPAddress (ipadd,
               netmask,
               index,
               &NTEContext,
               &NTEInstance);
```

"""

index is network adapter index.